# svmono and footnote inside boxedminipage

Tags: footnotes, minipage, sv-classes

Using the svmono class (downloaded from http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0 ), I get a latex error "Command \itshape invalid in math mode" with the following code:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\begin{document}

\begin{boxedminipage}[t]{4.5in}
Text\footnote{Text}
\end{boxedminipage}

\end{document}
```

I have no idea what itshape has to do with anything here.  If anyone has any idea how I can fix this, I'd be grateful!

Edit: I think the issue *might* be that inside a boxedminipage, the footnotes are numbered 'a,b,c' instead of '1,2,3' -- so latex is trying to type set a superscript italic 'a', etc.. I still have no idea how to fix this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like a bug in the class that you should report To Springer, but this is a possible workaround

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{amstext}
\let\oldthempfootnote\thempfootnote
\def\thempfootnote{\text{\oldthempfootnote}}
\begin{document}

\begin{boxedminipage}[t]{4.5in}
Text\footnote{Text}
\end{boxedminipage}

\end{document}
```